# Bootstrap slider navbar variable undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, slider, navbar

I'm working in a project using ASP.NET MVC + JQuery (frontend). I want to put a slider menu just like this one:

http://www.bootply.com/uugdMksxDP

I copied the code from bootply (where is working), but I just can't get it to work in mi project, because one variable goes as "undefined" even it exists in the DOM.

[Variable goes undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdmf.png)

but if I put the same statement in the console, it gives me the value I need.

I just can't figure it out. The .js is being loaded in a bundle, in the last place.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to wrap all of your code into:

```
$(function() {
    ... your code ...
});
```

It's a jquery short notation for `$(document).on('ready', function () { });`
and this makes sure your js will only be executed when the dom is ready for your code.

In addition you want to make sure jquery and bootstrap is implemented before your code loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! I did that but I get the same problem, the variable appears as undefined

Comment: It was a fast guess. You should add more of your code so it would be easier to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: and you did add bootstrap and its dependencys like jquery before your code?

Comment: Yes, its added in the first place